# PHP str_replace variable issue

Tags: php, str-replace

I'm new to PHP and i have a issue with my php str_replace.
I want to replace all . with , but it won't work.

This is the PHP code:

```
$price = 2.5;
$row['quantity'] = 3;
$totalprice = $price*$row['quantity'];
$total = str_replace(".",",",$totalprice);
echo number_format((float)$total, 2, '.', '');
```

Does anybody know what i do wrong?

Comment: Works fine for me: https://3v4l.org/TbivE

Comment: Everything is fine here too.

Comment: After the edit - you don't use the `$totalprice` in the `str_replace`-  what do you expect?

Comment: Wired issue but test `$total = str_replace(".",",","$totalprice");`

Comment: Wired what you do. `2.5*3` becomes `7.5` then `7,5` (str_rep.) and the number _format makes it to `7`, what is the logic behind that? also you replace period to komma and in number_format you want period again?

Comment: thanks for noticing @JustOnUnderMillions i didn't notice now it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

This outputs 7,00

```
$price = 2.5;
$row['quantity'] = 3;
$totalprice = $price*$row['quantity'];
$total = str_replace(".",",",$totalprice);
echo number_format($total, 2, ',', '');
```

If the output is supposed to be 7,50 than you can do this:

```
$price = 2.5;
$row['quantity'] = 3;
$totalprice = $price*$row['quantity'];
echo number_format($totalprice, 2, ',', '');
```

Comment: it won't work maybe that's because i'm using a `echo number_format((float)$total, 2, '.', '');` echo

Comment: what are the values in $price and $row? Edit your anwser with this info please.

Comment: 2.5 for the $price and 3 for the $row['quantity'] so then totalprice is 7.5

Comment: Add everything in your question that you have in your code. I dont see no number_format being used in your question.

Comment: `(float)` is not needed here. :)